# PyQtGraph crashes python

Tags: python-3.x, plot, pyqtgraph

so I have this issue that I cannot fix myself. The problem is that when I import pyqtgraph into python script or just run 'python -m pyqtgraph.example' in console it will crash python and I can't create graphs. There is no info just windows where it says something like: Python has stopped working..

I really need graphs and for me pyqtgraph is easyer than matplotlib.

P.S. It used to work when first installed but after some time it got this error !

Comment: I fear that if this is really all the information about the problem that you want to share here, you will not find any help. Imagine reading a question like this from someone else - what could you possibly do to help him?

Comment: Yes I understand but there is nothing more that I can provide you with. I looked for solution and couldn't find it. That is why I posted questing on stack overflow (I don't do that very often). Do you know if there is log file or something for pyqtgraph?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there is no module named `pyqtgraph.example`.

```
$ python -m pyqtgraph.example
/usr/bin/python: No module named pyqtgraph.example
```

You may want to run

```
$ python -m pyqtgraph.examples
```